# How to paginate dynamically in elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to remove records from elastic search by aggregation ,the query I am using is this

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "countfield": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "IaClaimChargeID",
        "size": 100,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "text": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "ChargeAmount"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I am doing is deleting all the docs where the doc_count is >1  .The problem is there are around 1 million records and ,I cant get all the records in single query .Is there is a solution where , i can give pagination size like from 1000 -5000 or is there any better solution to achieve this.

What I am doing is getting the doc_count and then running a delete query where doc_count >1 , for the value coming in output.

This is the output

```
 "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "$455512-Apr-09", // deleting by this key
          "hits" : []
          doc_count" : 1,
          "text" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : 1,
              "max_score" : 1.0,
             }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has an endpoint to delete records by certain condition, So you can use  `_delete_by_query` endpoint to that.

```
POST /put_your_index_name_goes_here/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "doc_count": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**SEE REF.** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Comment: So you mean to say ,there is no need of doing this aggregation ??. All I have to do is run this query?? And it will delete the documents where doc_count is 1?

Comment: Its not working .Though .Should i have to run aggregation before ?.I wonder on what basis it will calculate the doc_count

Comment: ohh my bad, I thought you already have `doc_count` field with value 1, that's why added only delete by query endpoint

Comment: I have doc_count value with me now .From aggregation but still how to use this query?

Comment: no tit will not work coz you don't have that field indexed

Comment: So you mean to say i have to reindex (create a new index with doc_count field)?

Comment: that will awesome and faster to delete with condition

Answer (score 0):

You can paginate like this by giving `from` and `size` parameters

```
 {
     "from" : 0, "size" : 10, 
      "aggs": {
        "countfield": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "IaClaimChargeID",
            "size": 100,
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            },
            "min_doc_count": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "text": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "_source": {
                  "includes": [
                    "ChargeAmount"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

You can look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-from-size)

Moreover the `size` with from is different from the size you give in aggregation ,size in aggregation signifies [bucketsize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html).Whereas the top most size refers to the number of documents (its default value is 10)